# Desktop.getDesktop not working

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop, eclipse-juno

So I am working in Java, but I am having some trouble with `Desktop.getDesktop()`

The code is fine, and it works on other people's computers (through Eclipse Juno), but it does not work on mine (through Eclipse Juno).

When I use `Desktop.getDesktop().open` to open a text file, nothing happens (even though I have notepad as my default viewer)

When I use `Desktop.getDesktop().browse` for a url, that doesn't work.  When I use `Desktop.getDesktop().open` for a url, it does work.

Is there any way to fix this?

All this code works on other computers, but not mine.

I'm running the program through Eclipse Juno (like the working versions are).

The .jar works, however (including when I put all the code I'm working on into a jar from my Eclipse Juno).

Comment: Have you tried checking what `Desktop#isDesktopSupported()` and `Desktop#isSupported(Desktop.Action)` returns?

Comment: I did.  It says Desktop is supported